# Using Microsoft.Graph .NET Core library to retrieve Risk Detections

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

Are there any methods within Microsoft.Graph to gather Risk Detections and Risky Users from the API? I am unable to find methods to build these requests under the Identity class.

Otherwise, is there a way to use an existing GraphServiceClient to build a request for an arbitrary Graph API Endpoint?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the APIs of [List riskDetections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/riskdetection-list?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [List riskyUsers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/riskyuser-list?view=graph-rest-1.0). However, they have no SDK method about C#. You could just obtain access token and then make Get request to list them.